# How to make unlimited spawning enemies/asteroids in cocos2d for iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

is there any example that shows a asteroid like game with unlimited enemy/asteroids spawning?

How can I do this with cocos2d **and box2d**?

PS: They should come from all directions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is so general that you seem like just crawling into the dark.

What you want is to set a maximum amount of enemies and then randomly (possibly biased by the difference between maximum enemies and current enemies, so that if there are less enemies the chance to spawn a new one is higher) you spawn them.

You can do it in `-(void)update:(ccTime)dt` method which is automatically called by cocos2d life cycle on every repaint of the whole display. You can enable this automatic scheduling by calling `[self scheduleUpdate]` in the init method of your `CCLayer` subclass.